# Use latexmk on dtx file and then run it again on the tex file(s) it creates

Tags: latexmk, dtx

I'm using `latexmk` on a `dtx` file that generates tex files as follows:

```
%<*driver>
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
\file{\jobname_allnotes.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{longcalc,shortcalc,annotation,notes}}
\file{\jobname_somenotes.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{shortcalc,annotation}}          
\file{\jobname.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{nonotes}}          
}
\endbatchfile
%</driver>
```

I'm trying to get `latexmk` to run `pdflatex` on `dtx` file once, and then run it again on the tex files the `dtx` file generates. Is this possible? Or do I need a standard `makefile` to do this?